# How to find the location of a string in a text file

Tags: c#, string, file, text, location

I'm trying to figure out how to find a certain string and display how many lines down it is in a text file.

For example let's saying I'm trying to find the string "I'm a string" in a text file then also have the location of the string(As in lines down) recorded in a variable.

Anyone got any tips too accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would read in the file, then loop through each line searching for the text. Something like...

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt");

int count = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    count++;
    if (line.indexOf("I'm a string") > -1) {
       // found it
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like a HW Question, I will not be posting the complete solution, but only pointers and guidelines.

You basically want to scan through your whole text file, letter by letter, reading the next n chars, where n is the length of your search string.
If that set matches your search string, you have your answer.
The number of "\n" you encounter is the number of lines you had to traverse through.

There exist simpler regex solutions also.. You should try looking at those.

Comment: Actually not homework :P working on a small password manager application for practice that stores the passwords in a file and I had to have a way of locating them, Thanks none the less though :D

Comment: You probably want to try a regex based solution. In this case, it will be much faster to code at the cost of an extra library.

Answer (score 0):

Better than ReadAllLines:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
```